# Google listing URLs that don't exist anymore

Tags: seo, google, url

About two weeks ago I uploaded few sitemap files (few hunded thousand links total), and after a week, I saw that Google has indexed most of those links.

Now, a week ago I cleaned my database a bit, which lead to about 30% of links to be invalid. I then updated my sitemap files with only valid links, and reuploaded them to Google Webmaster Tools.

And here we are, a week from that, and Google still displays those invalid links.

Do I need to do anything else in order to stop Google from doing that, or do I need to just wait more?

Comment: Are these _invalid links_ in the SERPs or in GWTs "crawl errors" report?

Answer (score 3):

If your the URLs give a 404 error then you just have to wait more.
It may take even several weeks for Google to update.

Answer (score 2):

Google will **never** stop showing pages that used to exist but which no longer do in the 404 error report.  Googlebot will periodically come back and crawl these URLs forever as well.

I have pages that disappeared over 10 years ago, are not linked from anywhere anymore, and yet Google still seems wistful about them.

If any of the pages have valid replacements, you can redirect them to another page.   If there is no replacement, then you could return "410 Gone" status to at least indicate that the removal is permanent.